# Is there any reason to lock on something other than new object()?

Tags: c#, .net, locking, parallel-processing

```
object theLock = new object();

...


lock (theLock)
{
    ...
}
```

I always use a `new object()` for this, but I'm wondering: are there any circumstances in which you would lock on a more specific type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of a `new`, the `Type` doesn't matter, the instance do. In this case you're talking about a **synclock** object : an object which is used to lock code(s) section(s) to prevent concurrent access.

Using another `Type` than `object` for a synclock is a waste of memory because you don't use this instance for anything else.

There're circumstances in which you can lock another type : when you need to lock a specific instance.
The main problem is : the instance must be initialized to lock it. And in most cases, you want to synclock the initilization of the instance :)

But in some case, you can lock the instance directly ; like a dictionary for example (well almost directly in this case ;)).

```
private Dictionary<string,string> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();

public void AddValue(string key, string value)
{
    lock (((IDictionary)_dictionary).SyncRoot)    // SyncRoot recommended
    {
       if (!_dictionary.ContainsValue(value))
            _dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

But the point is : even if this will work, always ask yourself : "Is it not a better idea to create a specific locking object instead" ?

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about the `SyncRoot` property.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinon any reference type can be locked, the reason why a dummy object is used is to avoid common locking pitfalls:

> The common constructs lock (this),
>   lock (typeof (MyType)), and lock
>   ("myLock") violate this guideline:
>
> ```
>   lock (this) is a problem if the instance can be accessed publicly.
>
>
>   lock (typeof (MyType)) is a problem if MyType is publicly
> ```
>
> accessible.
>
> ```
>   lock("myLock") is a problem because any other code in the process
> ```
>
> using the same string, will share the
>   same lock.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you know that article [Lock Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

In general, avoid locking on a **public** type, or instances beyond your code's control. The common constructs *lock (this), lock (typeof (MyType))*, and *lock ("myLock")* violate this guideline:

- *lock (this)* is a problem if the
  instance can be accessed publicly.
- *lock (typeof (MyType))* is a problem
  if *MyType* is publicly accessible.
- *lock(“myLock”)* is a problem since any
  other code in the process using the
  same string, will share the same
  lock.

Best practice is to define a **private** object to lock on, or a **private static** object variable to protect data common to all instances.