# What is the best static type of object to lock on? Is there any better than others?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, locking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any reason to lock on something other than new object()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361284/is-there-any-reason-to-lock-on-something-other-than-new-object)

I am wondering what is the best private static object to lock on, if indeed there is a difference.

At the moment, most of my code consits of :

```
private static object m_lockObject = new object();

lock(m_lockObject)
{
    ..critical thread code here
}
```

Instead of locking on just a object, should I use a different type? Like a custom class instance, an int, or a string, etc...?  Or does it not matter?

Thanks

Comment: Using an `object` is fine and quite common. Locking on a `String` could cause unexpected results due to String interning if you're not careful.

Comment: and locking on a struct, for example an `int`, just wouldn't be possible (unless it was boxed, and I wouldn't want to go down that road as it would be messy, even if it's possible).

Comment: I think [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361284/is-there-any-reason-to-lock-on-something-other-than-new-object "lock object") will answer your question.

Comment: `object` is standard. Just don't use a value type(boxing mess) or `string`(interning mess).

Comment: @Servy its not a duplciate, cause im asking whats the best type, not is there any reason

Comment: @jordan.peoples It's pretty darn close.  Technically there is no "best" type.  Different situations call for different responses; that question indicates when it is and is not appropriate to use what.  If you don't consider that an exact duplicate then this question would just need to be closed as "not constructive", and that seems less helpful to you.

Comment: @Servy, yes but when i searched stack Overflow for "whats the best type to lock on" or "whats the best lock object in C#" nothing came up. Hence why i came here, so that future people who type in the same question as me will have a answer ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Lock` statement is just a syntactic sugar for underlying **[`Monitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx)** object. For the purpose of locking, it uses a reference. It doesn't matter what reference it is - from the Monitor's point of view! Locking on `string` however may cause unexpected results due to strings being **[interned](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/08/understanding-c-stringintern-m.html)** for example. And locking on value types would get you an exception because of boxing.

TL;DR version - you're doing it quite right (if the `static` part is really your desired behaviour)

Comment: static is required. i want no more than one thread executing said code block at any given time.

Comment: @jordan.peoples Just to add here; `object` is the ideal class to use for this, because it's the "lightest weight" class that fulfills the requirement of `lock`